# better to return generic response entity type to handle errors or to throw exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is it better to return a generic response entity like `ResponseEntity<*>` or to throw an exception when an error happens?

Consider the following kotlin code:

```
@PostMapping("/customer")
fun handleRequest(@Valid @RequestBody customer: Customer, result: BindingResult): ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse> {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
     // #### Use generic response entity for return type 
     // #### Or throw error to be picked up in controller advice ?
    }

    val isValid = recapcthaService.validate(...)

    if(!isValid){
     // #### Use generic response entity for return type
     // #### Or throw error to be picked up in controller advice ?
    }
}
```

The request handler function returns `ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse>` however in the case of an error state like validation errors or recapctha validation failure I want to return a different return a  `ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>`  as `ErrorResponse` is common response type for errors/exceptions.

In this case is it better to change the return type to `ResponseEntity<*>` or throw an exception to be picked up by controller advice?

Answer (score 2):

This is more like a recommendation. Obviously both approach works fine. I would wrap `ErrorResponse` inside a custom `ValidationeException`. This way you can throw this exception from any where with error response. Also would use custom `@ControllerAdvice` to handle the `ValidationException` and map it into `ResponseEntity`. This can be useful for any other custom exceptions you would like to map. for example you can also move the binding result to read from `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

Something like

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
   @Override
   protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headera, HttpStatus status, WebREquest request) {return ResponseEntity...};
   @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class) }
   protected ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleValidationErrors(ValidationExceptionex) {return ResponseEntity...};
}
```

For furthur explanation you can take a look here https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Agree with `s7vr`'s opinion. It's better to throw an exception to be picked up by controller advice because you can extract the logic of constructing common errors together with this controller advice. And you can define several exceptions to separate errors. If you build with `ResponseEntity<*>`, you code may be like this:

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
 return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(BaseRespVo.builder().code(error).data(errorDesc).build());
}

val isValid = recapcthaService.validate(...)

if(!isValid){
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(BaseRespVo.builder().code(invalid).data(invalidDesc).build());
}
```

This construct code looks bloated. So better to extract it in a common place.